# Eclipse Activiti Designer Custom Extension

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, activiti, designer

I want to extend the Activiti Designer plugin for eclipse. I tried to follow the example in the [documentation](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#eclipseDesignerInstallation) but I don't know how to apply my extension to the Activiti Designer. In the documentation there is a user library group called "Activiti Designer Extensions" where I need to add my jar ... but I don't have such a group. Any ideas what the problem might be here or how I can deploy the extension of the plugin otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

those eclipse plugins are abandoned since 2015 .. I would recommend you to check out something like http://bpmn.io if you are planning to create tooling, it is JavaScript-based and highly extensible and there is already a bpmn.io extension for VS Code https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salaboy.vs-code-bpmn-io